# How does EF work in WPF/Silverlight apps?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4.1, inotifypropertychanged

I've been trying for a while to wrap my mind around 2 concepts at once, learning MVVM (and one of the hard things has been trying to figure out which framework to use.  We didn't even know how many there were until a few weeks ago) and also I'm trying to learn Entity Framework 4.2.

This is for a WPF app that we're going to be writing.

I've gotten Julia Lerman's book and I'm also going through an online training course on EF, but one thing I still don't get, and haven't seen any example of yet, is how to handle something like the INotifyPropertyChanged interface with the classes created via EF, regardless of whether we use MVVM or not, working with INotifyPropertyChanged is vital.

So, let me ask here the plain question:

Do you allow EF to create all of the data access classes that reflect all of the data in your database, and then duplicate much of that code so I can get it to work with INotifyPropertyChanged?  Or is there some other way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I was baffled when the thought came to me, that I'd have to map every data object to a new one only implementing INPC on top of it.

Then I found a trick: assuming you're going to use WCF, it automatically implements INPC. 
For the collections, just go into the Service Reference configuration, and set it so that it gives you ObservableCollection as default collection type.

That's it, you're set for MVVM =)

Comment: What? WCF implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?  Are you kidding me? I didn't know that.  Does that depend upon the datatypes you're returning? For example, I wrote all of my WCF services a few years ago (2008 or earlier, I think), and I certainly didn't know about INPC back then.  All of my WCF classes return strongly typed datasets.  I'm assuming that those don't implement INPC, am I correct about that?

Comment: Go and check your types in your client. Widen your eyes when you see the "PropertyChanged" event on each and every one of them. =p

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ViewModel` is created with the needs of the `View` in mind, only in very simply cases the `ViewModel` and your `Entity` are the same class. Normally you have an `Entity` class and a `ViewModel` class.
`INotifyPropertyChanged` is only one of the reasons for this. There are others like conversions, validation, meaningful error messages, aggregation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used Entity Framework in several of my WPF applications.  The first time I used EF Database first.  It was pretty tricky to get the model exactly the way I wanted it, and once it was working, then I had to go through and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on my entity classes.

Recently, I have started using EntityFramework CodeFirst with 4.1, I have found it is much much easier to handle all of the property changed stuff.  I generally create a base class with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on it and inherit my entities from that.

As far as the ViewModel, I also started out worrying about this framework or that framework.  Later I decided to just roll my own.  Sure, the frameworks have some interesting capabilities, but for learning, I found it much easier to get into it by creating my own ViewModelBase class and inheriting all of my ViewModels from that.

ViewModelBase typically implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Later I created a ViewModel monitor class which would have a collection of ViewModels.  To look them up, I gave ViewModelBase a FriendlyName property so that each type of inherited ViewModel could have a name set for it (my types are typically RecordMaintenanceViewModel, NavigationViewModel, ShellViewModel, etc) and I generally will inherit my used view-specific ViewModels from those.  So on the ShipmentView in my shipping program, The ShipmentViewModel is inherited from a CollectionViewModel, which is inherited from the ViewModelBase.  In this way I have functionality divided up into discreet sections allowing me to handle specific scenarios.

I generally port my ViewModel base over to every project, and often take my middle ViewModels; sometimes I have to recreate them though.